# How to compare two classes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, class, comparison

Let's suppose I have a `Class` like this:

```
Class MyClass(Of Template)
    'Some things here
End Class
```

So far, so good. However, I would like to do things depending on the template, like

```
Class MyClass(Of Template)
    'Some things here
    Public Sub MyMethod
        'If Template is MyOtherClass Then
        '    do some things
        'Else
        '    do some other things
        'End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Of course, I could give an object and then check whether `TypeOf (obj) Is MyOtherClass`, but that seems to be less intuitive for me. Is there a way to compare two classes in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare the type

```
Class MyClass(Of Template)
    'Some things here

    Public Sub MyMethod
        If GetType(Template) is GetType(MyOtherClass) Then
            do some things
        Else
            do some other things
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

But that seems like a bad thing to do. The point of OO is to have the logic in it's respective class instead of doing this.

Comment: This is a step of refactorization. I have a class where each possible class is handled by a copy-pasted function. I intend to first merge these functions into one, then create an interface and inherit it by several classes. Since I am not really eloquent in VB, I have shortcomings when it comes to the syntax, but I surely know what I want to achieve and the thing I lack is: knowledge about the syntax. After googling I did not find relevant documents, hence I asked the questions